# PLSQL UPDATE OF with Join

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a PLSQL statement that updates the money in the inventory of the characters with the money from all the creatures they've fought

The following is the code I've been trying:

```
   DECLARE
        inv_money character.money%TYPE;
        CURSOR updmoney IS
            SELECT *
            FROM character
            WHERE id IN (SELECT character_id FROM inst_creature)
        FOR UPDATE OF money;
    BEGIN
        FOR v_character IN updmoney LOOP

          SELECT inst_creature.money
          INTO inv_money
          FROM inst_creature,character
          WHERE inst_creature.character_id = character.ID;

          UPDATE character
          SET money = money+inv_money
          WHERE CURRENT OF updmoney;
        END LOOP;
        COMMIT;
    END;
```

There is a character_id in the inst_creature table which is used to define the character that fought that creature.

I'm getting the error 
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows.

I've been trying to fix it by using Google to get a solution but nothing has been working so far. Any thoughts?

Comment: What happens when a character has killed more than one monster? ORA-01422, that's what.

Comment: @APC Ah, I see. Is there any solution to this for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when a character has killed more than one monster? ORA-01422, that's what. The SELECT ... INTO syntax populates a scalar value, that is one row. When the query returns more than one row PL/SQL hurls ORA-01422.

> " Is there any solution to this for it to work?"

The easiest way is to fix the query so it returns one row. As you're just adding money to the character's trove, you can use an aggregate:

```
      SELECT sum(inst_creature.money)
      INTO inv_money
      FROM inst_creature,character
      WHERE inst_creature.character_id = character.ID;
```

So you get one row per character, and one update per character.

Comment: Watch out though - [the monster is never dead](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NotQuiteDead).